# Neo4j: Cypher query returns duplicate results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two graphs built like this :

```
CREATE (level1a:Bug {name: 'a'})
CREATE (level1b:Bug {name: 'b'})
CREATE (level2c:Bug {name: 'c'})
CREATE (level2d:Bug {name: 'd'})
CREATE (level3e:Bug {name: 'e'})
CREATE (level3f:Bug {name: 'f'})
CREATE (level3g:Bug {name: 'g'})
CREATE (level3h:Bug {name: 'h'})

CREATE (level1a)-[:LINK]->(level2c)
CREATE (level1b)-[:LINK]->(level2d)
CREATE (level2c)-[:LINK]->(level3e)
CREATE (level2c)-[:LINK]->(level3f)
CREATE (level2d)-[:LINK]->(level3g)
CREATE (level2d)-[:LINK]->(level3h)
```

And also available here : http://console.neo4j.org/?id=duplicate_bug2

When I execute the query :

```
MATCH (a:Bug {name: 'a'})-[:LINK]->()-[:LINK]->(end) return end
```

I get the expected two nodes (f and e). But if I do two match queries like this :

```
MATCH (a:Bug {name: 'a'})-[:LINK]->()-[:LINK]->(end)
MATCH (b:Bug {name: 'b'})-[:LINK]->()-[:LINK]->(end2)
return end, end2
```

I get duplicates nodes in end and end2. Why is this? The two graphs are not even connected!

BR,
S

Answer (score 3):

Since both matches will return multiple rows and there is no correlation between the two match statements it will generate a cross product of the two result sets. In this case it is 2x2 so you get four rows of each node with each node.

I think what you are after is something like this query. It finds all of the ends from the first match, combines them in a collection and then repeats the process for the second match. Then it returns a single row in the result set with all of the ends of `a` and all of the ends of `b` regardless of how many there are at the end of each match.

```
MATCH (a:Bug {name: 'a'})-[:LINK]->()-[:LINK]->(end)
with collect(end) as end
MATCH (b:Bug {name: 'b'})-[:LINK]->()-[:LINK]->(end2)
return  end, collect(end2) as end2
```

Comment: Where do I combine the result set? Even if I return only end it will still contain duplicates.

Comment: For every result in the first match the second match is performed. Since there are two rows it is performed twice. Since the second match itself also produces two rows the end result is four rows. I agree the language in the original answer is clunky so i changed it.